just installed latest version of Ubuntu & app center won't open
I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu (24.10) on an old Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop and the app center won't open. I rebooted the laptop. I ran the search for any updates and the app center still wouldn't open. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Did you try starting it from the terminal? What do your logs say about it?
